# Как заставить redux обновить состояние только один раз?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql

Я использую Apollo GQL. При получении данных data мне нужно обновить состояние в сторе redux. При попытке написать код типа:

```
if (this.props.data){
      this.props.onLoadingStart();
    }
```

Redux циклит обновление. Мне нужно при каждом обновлении data обновлять состояние только один раз так, чтобы не возникал бесконечный цикл. Я добавил `loadingFlag`, который при монтировании компонента становится true, затем в `render()` я выполняю

```
if (this.props.data) {
      if (this.props.loadingFlag) {
        this.props.onLoadData(this.props.data);
        this.props.onLoadingFinish();
      }
    }
```

`this.props.onLoadingFinish()` возвращает `loadingFlag` в состояние false и цикл не возникает. Но вся эта логика работает только при монтировании. При обновлении data в последующем, react просто не попадает в цикл для обновления данных, т.к. `loadingFlag === false`. Я пробовал поставить `this.props.onLoadingStart()` в `componentDidUpdate` - возникает бесконечный цикл. Что мне делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Данные попадают из компонента сверху, так? Вы можете в компонент сверху, который передает в props данные, добавить флаг?

Ваша задача же звучит "Обновить стор только тогда, когда придут новые данные". С приходом данных добавьте не только данные, но и флаг.

Когда приходят данные, изменяйте сверху this.props.loadingFlag на true. Когда this.props.loadingFlag === true, делайте операцию и записываете   this.props.loadingFlag === false. Получается примерно так

```js
    if (this.props.data) {
        if (this.props.loadingFlag === true) {
          this.props.onLoadData(this.props.data);
          this.props.onLoadingFinish();
          this.props.loadingFlag === false;
        }
      }
```

2. Если нельзя сделать пункт 1, то сами. Попробуйте разделить компонент принимающий данные и отображение. Компонент по приему данных получит эти данные(сверху) пусть будет GQLProvider. Передаст эти данные вниз(целевому компоненту с флагом) и обнулит у себя this.props.data. Так же будет проверять,

this.props.data. Просто вместо отправки данных в redux будет отправлять компоненту ниже флаг и данные.

3. Пересмотрите архитектуру. Возможно данные должны попадать не через целевой компонент, а через хранилище redux(спец. компонент допустим), а далее целевой компонент подписывается на изменения, таким образом получая нужные данные.

В таком случае GQLProvider отправляет данные в redux и зануляет у себя, а целевой компонент получает данные по подписке/событию на хранилище.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему тем, что монтирую этот компонент заново при каждом запросе. Если `loading - return null`, если `!loading` - возвращается и монтируется компонент, который заново записывает состояние в store